# Absolute paths not allowed on Dart WebComponent

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, web-component

My little Dart/Polymer sample works nice so far.
[(GitHub)](https://github.com/MikeMitterer/DART-Sample-PolymerHelloWorld)

Here is the yaml file I use:

```yaml
name: PolymerHelloWorld
environment:
  sdk: any
dependencies:
  browser: any
  polymer: any
  shadow_dom: any
  mdv: any

transformers:
-  polymer:
    entry_points:
    - web/index.html
    - web/hello-world/hello-world.html
    - web/stopwatch/stopwatch.html
```

"pub build" produces: (Live again under [GH](http://goo.gl/y4IuPy))
[image]

From my understanding now I have 2 webcomponents: hello-world and stopwatch

I made a second project, completely independent form PolymerHelloWorld.
Here is the index.html:
[image]

I get this error message

```
pub build
Building PolymerSecondWorld...
[Error from polymer (Linter) on PolymerSecondWorld|web/index.html]:
web/index.html:4:5: absolute paths not allowed: "https://rawgithub.com/MikeMitterer/DART-Sample-PolymerHelloWorld/master/build/hello-world/hello-world.html"
```

**Isn't this the idea of webcomponents?** Do I miss something?

[**Update**]
 
I added [DART-Sample-PolymerElementConsumer](https://github.com/MikeMitterer/DART-Sample-PolymerElementConsumer) to my GH-Repo. It includes the whole polymer stuff... This sample is **not** a Dart-Sample. It uses polymer to import the component. At least - it tries to...

Here is the HTML it try to run:
 
https://rawgithub.com/MikeMitterer/DART-Sample-PolymerElementConsumer/master/web/index.html

Codeview:
https://raw.github.com/MikeMitterer/DART-Sample-PolymerElementConsumer/master/web/index.html

The HTML-Page shows no error message - nothing. Just the headline but nothing from the webcomponent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to import Polymer elements they have to be in a Dart package (e.g pub.dartlang.org).
You add the package to you `pubspec.yaml` to import the package into your project and
then you can import the elements/components from the packages directory.

Polymer is also very delicate about the import paths within a Dart project
and something like you tried definitively won't work
(this could work in JavaScript though)
but this would require to execute code (included within the loaded component) loaded at runtime
which Dart doesn't support yet. All code has to be available at compile time.

Some discussions about this topic:

- [trouble importing components using href="package:..."](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!msg/web/uTfFPU2_HZM/517Ev4xdMDsJ)
- [should HTML Imports support package: scheme?](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=12867)
- [How can I import a custom element in both HTML and Dart? (workaround included)](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!msg/web/MmK3niony-I/UXVgaLAZZZ0J)
- [improve canonicalization issues with html-imports involving packages](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=15953)

**EDIT**

I looked at your code and tried to understand your comment and extended my answer accordingly.

To be able to import components from a package the components have to be in the `lib` directory of the package you want to import.
The web page using (importing) elements has to be a Dart project (package) which imports the component package in 'pubspec.yaml'. For the web application (index.html, ...) `web` is the correct directory within the package.

Comment: This was exactly the reason why I tried to import the compiled hello-world. A webcomponent should be language + toolset (framework) independent.

Comment: Ok, but you can only import from the package directory like 'packages/somecomponentpackage/theelement.html'. I also don't see where you have the DART-SamplePolymerHelloWorld in your pubspec.yaml.

Comment: @MikeMitterer I extended my answer.

Comment: I updated my question. I move the whole consumer sample to GH... As explained in my updated question: The consumer has nothing todo with dart.

Comment: This won't work. The consumer has to be a Dart web application. You have to create the consumer application in Dart and build it with dart2js/pub build (transpile) to make it a JavaScript application that runs on other browsers than Dartium. The package containing the components has raw Dart components that have to be transpiled with the consuming application.

Comment: Why, the whole philosophy of Web Components and polymer is to be language and tools independent.

Comment: Dart is not yet dynamic enough to work this way. You can't compile at runtime. You would have to implement the Dart2Js transpiler in JavaScript and ship it with your application so the webpage can transpile arbitary Dart code to JavaScript as it gets loaded.

Comment: Hmmm, a bit frustrating. Hope this changes asap. To me that's more a design problem than a technical problem. Anyway - thx! for your help.

Comment: It's only a technical problem besides the Design decision to make a Language that is not JavaScript but apps built with it should run on browsers only capable of JavaScript.
It won't happen very soon AFAIK.

Comment: For dynamic features you have to utilize JavaScript itself via Dart-JS-interop. I don't know PolymerJS and don't know how well it works in the same page with PolymerDart or if PolymerJS supports dynamic loading of components. But AFAIK this is currently the only option.